# How to build a Checkbox List component starting from a Checkbox component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, storybook

I've managed to write a Checkbox component to be used in Storybook which works fine.

Now, I need to build on top of if a CheckboxList component that can have multiple checkboxes, and the component has an optional prop saying the initial state of each of the checkboxes if there are checked or not.

When a checkbox is clicked, the state should update.

Here is the Checkbox component so far:

```
import {
  StyledCheckboxIndicator,
  StyledCheckboxRoot,
  StyledCheckIcon,
  StyledMinusIcon,
} from './form-checkbox.styles';
import * as Checkbox from '@radix-ui/react-checkbox';

interface FormCheckboxProps extends Checkbox.CheckboxProps {
  checkboxIndicatorProps?: Checkbox.CheckboxIndicatorProps;
  isError?: boolean;
}


export const FormCheckbox = ({
  checkboxIndicatorProps,
  isError,
  ...checkboxRootProps
}: FormCheckboxProps) => {
  const { disabled, checked } = checkboxRootProps;
  return (
    <StyledCheckboxRoot {...checkboxRootProps} $isError={isError}>
      <StyledCheckboxIndicator {...checkboxIndicatorProps}>
        {checked === 'indeterminate' ? (
          <StyledMinusIcon disabled={disabled} />
        ) : (
          <StyledCheckIcon disabled={disabled} />
        )}
      </StyledCheckboxIndicator>
    </StyledCheckboxRoot>
  );
};
```

Not sure if styling is necessary but here they are:

```
import styled from 'styled-components';
import * as Checkbox from '@radix-ui/react-checkbox';

import { ReactComponent as CheckIcon } from 'svgs/states/check-solid.svg';
import { ReactComponent as MinusIcon } from 'svgs/minus.svg';

export const StyledCheckboxRoot = styled(Checkbox.Root)<{ $isError?: boolean }>`
  button {
    all: unset;
  }
  background-color: ${({ $isError, theme }) =>
    $isError ? theme.colors.error.lightest : theme.colors.background.secondary};
  border-radius: 0.2rem;
  border: 1px solid
    ${({ $isError, theme }) => ($isError ? theme.colors.error.main : theme.colors.border.dropdown)};
  height: 2rem;
  width: 2rem;
  transition: border-color 100ms, background-color 100ms;

  &:hover {
    border-color: ${({ theme }) => theme.colors.border.hover};
  }
  &:focus {
    outline: none;
    border-color: ${({ theme }) => theme.colors.info.main};
  }
  &[data-state='checked'] {
    background-color: ${({ theme }) => theme.colors.success.toggle};
    border-color: ${({ $isError, theme }) =>
      $isError ? theme.colors.error.main : theme.colors.success.toggle};
    &:hover {
      border-color: ${({ theme }) => theme.colors.border.hover};
    }
    &:focus {
      border-color: ${({ theme }) => theme.colors.info.main};
    }
  }
  &[data-state='indeterminate'] {
    background-color: ${({ theme }) => theme.colors.success.toggle};
    border-color: ${({ $isError, theme }) =>
      $isError ? theme.colors.error.main : theme.colors.success.toggle};
    &:hover {
      border-color: ${({ theme }) => theme.colors.border.hover};
    }
    &:focus {
      border-color: ${({ theme }) => theme.colors.info.main};
    }
  }
  &[data-disabled] {
    pointer-events: none;
    background-color: ${({ theme }) => theme.colors.background.disabled};
    &[data-state='checked'] {
      background-color: ${({ theme }) => theme.colors.background.disabled};
      border-color: ${({ theme }) => theme.colors.border.dropdown};
    }
    &[data-state='indeterminate'] {
      background-color: ${({ theme }) => theme.colors.background.disabled};
      border-color: ${({ theme }) => theme.colors.border.dropdown};
    }
  }
`;

export const StyledCheckboxIndicator = styled(Checkbox.Indicator)`
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
`;

export const StyledCheckIcon = styled(CheckIcon)<{ disabled?: boolean }>`
  fill: ${({ disabled, theme }) => (disabled ? theme.colors.toggle : theme.colors.background.main)};
  width: 1.4rem;
`;

export const StyledMinusIcon = styled(MinusIcon)<{ disabled?: boolean }>`
  fill: ${({ disabled, theme }) => (disabled ? theme.colors.toggle : theme.colors.background.main)};
  width: 1.2rem;
`;
```

Now, based on the above component, here is the CheckboxGroup component:

```
import { Fragment } from 'react';
interface CheckboxGroupProps {
  children: ReactNode;
  defaultChecked?: boolean | undefined;
  onChange?: ((e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void) | undefined;
}

export const CheckboxGroup = ({ children }: CheckboxGroupProps) => {
  return <Fragment>{children}</Fragment>;
};
```

And here is the Storybook file:

```
    import { ComponentMeta, ComponentStory } from '@storybook/react';
    import { FormCheckbox } from 'components/atoms';
    import { useState } from 'react';
    
    import { CheckboxGroup } from './checkbox-group';
    import { StorybookCheckboxGroupSetupProps } from './checkbox-group.types';
    
    const options = [
      {
        label: 'first',
        value: 'Chocolate',
        name: 'selection-box',
      },
      {
        label: 'second',
        value: 'Candy',
        name: 'selection-box',
      },
      {
        label: 'third',
        value: 'Lollipop',
        name: 'selection-box',
      },
    ];
    
    export default {
      title: 'Molecules/CheckboxGroup',
      component: CheckboxGroup,
      parameters: {},
      args: {},
      argTypes: {
        multipleOption: {
          type: Array<boolean>,
        },
      },
    } as ComponentMeta<typeof CheckboxGroup>;
    
const CheckboxGroupSetup = ({
  handleCheckboxOnChange,
  currentOption,
}: StorybookCheckboxGroupSetupProps) => {
  console.log('currentOption 4: ', currentOption); // LOG HERE 
  return (
    <CheckboxGroup>
      {options.map((option) => {
        return (
          <FormCheckbox
            onClick={() => handleCheckboxOnChange}
            key={option.label}
            defaultChecked={currentOption.includes(option.label)}
          />
        );
      })}
    </CheckboxGroup>
  );
};

const useControlledCheckboxGroup = (initialValues: Array<string> = ['second']) => {
  const [currentOption, setCurrentOption] = useState<Array<string>>(initialValues);
  console.log('currentOption 1: ', currentOption); // LOG HERE 
  const handleCheckboxOnChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    let updatedList = [...currentOption];
    if (event.target.checked) {
      updatedList = [...currentOption, event.target.value];
    } else {
      updatedList.splice(currentOption.indexOf(event.target.value), 1);
    }
    console.log('currentOption 2: ', currentOption); // LOG HERE 
    setCurrentOption(updatedList);
  };
  console.log('currentOption 3: ', currentOption); // LOG HERE 
  return { currentOption, handleCheckboxOnChange };
};
    
    export const radioGroup: ComponentStory<typeof CheckboxGroup> = () => {
      const { currentOption, handleCheckboxOnChange } = useControlledCheckboxGroup();
    
      return (
        <CheckboxGroupSetup
          currentOption={currentOption}
          handleCheckboxOnChange={handleCheckboxOnChange}
        />
      );
    };
```

For the above example it should show 3 checkboxes with the second one checked and the other two unchecked. It does it, it shows them correctly.

However, after this when the checkboxes are clicked even though they change (`aria-checked="true"` becomes `aria-checked="false"` and `data-state="checked"` becomes `data-state="unchecked"`), the state isn't updating.

I've put four logs, it only logs 1, 3 and 4 at first render and then no matter what is clicked, there is no log shown in console.

Is there anything wrong in the implementation?